# Adding Cinnamon to Coffee?

Tags: brewing-process, flavor, ground-coffee, drip-brew, flavored-coffee

I have seen a lot of articles saying adding cinnamon to one's coffee makes it taste a little better? I don't see how could adding something make something original taste even better? has someone tried this ? and can you please describe this taste to me? also, can I add cinnamon to black coffee? The articles I read only described adding it to latte and milk based coffees?

Comment: Seems like it's a subjective thing.  Some people think sugar in their coffee makes it taste 'better' while others think sugar makes it taste 'worse'.

Comment: Once upon a time I was sent a gift of 'traditional' Honduran coffee from a friend who was originally from there.  I don't know if it was a family recipe or not, but the grounds had what smelled like nutmeg and cinnamon added.  It was very flavorful, and interesting.  You can drink this black.  My suggestion.. just try it and see what you think!  Worst case, you waste a cup of coffee.  I feel like this is similar to marinading steak.  Some people find it unbearable to add anything beyond salt pepper and butter to a steak.. while others swear by complicated marinades  It comes down to preference

Answer (score 5):

I've tried it and liked it, but that's just because I like the taste of cinnamon in general. It doesn't enhance the taste of the coffee itself, per se, but adds its own additional flavor, which does tend to marry nicely with the coffee's. And yes, you can certainly put it in black. Actually, back in my drip coffee days, I'd sometimes put a couple sprinkles in with the grounds before brewing to spice it up. Good stuff!

Answer (score 4):

i think it doesn't make coffee taste better. it's up to you, if you like coffee and like cinnamon - then go for it, why not?

generally speaking, adding spices makes the coffee good for you. it is customary in eastern cultures to add cardamom to coffee and serve it on high political summits and stuff. cardamon coffee calms you down and gives you calm energy. it also quenches your thirst, as opposed to normal straight [keepvid](https://keepvid.works/) coffee only making you thirstier. ginger coffee, for example, ginger coffee is well popular amongst athletes, it restores your energy after big workout, restores your inner balance. nutmeg coffee is good for male potency. black pepper coffee is great to flush toxins. it's all based on properties of spices. spiced up coffee is good for you.

cinnamon coffee, to return to it, i personally don't like the taste, but i drink it once in a while. it's good for you! cinnamon it counteracts negative effects of caffeine on your body. It promotes better blood flow, cleans the blood, helps with flu as good as nyquil does. there's truly a lot to cinnamon coffee. i recommend you try it, even if you hate it, - it's good for you.

-- edit

my answer has been changed by moderators to remove the link to the article from which i have picked up lots of wisdom on how spices make coffee more beneficial for you. this action has prohibited interested individuals from following up on the subject and picking up some knowledge elsewhere. i've always thought that if something is written somewhere that you want to mention in a post, the best course of action is to describe the idea in a few words and let readers chose whether they want to follow up on more info or not. i guess i was wrong. i apologize for shoving links in your faces. i still think this article has great information, so i will copy whole chunk about cinnamon coffee..

> We want coffee to promote some health improving processes. So go
>   ahead, put that coffee pot on the stove, or power on your Keurig
>   machine, and make that favorite roast of yours, and while it’s boiling
>   and cooking, continue reading this article – the best is yet to come.
>   Below we will talk about several spices that promote health benefits
>   when added to your favorite cup of jo, or even a latte or a mocha
>   drink. Iced coffee can work here too, but best effects will surface in
>   hot drinks, when hot water makes spices emit their beneficial
>   qualities. Nevertheless, if you like or if it’s summer, you can make
>   iced coffee good for you too, just make sure to add spices before
>   chilling and icing your drink.
>
> **Cinnamon + coffee = forget your nyquil**
>
> Second spice to mention is cinnamon. It has stronger smell and taste
>   than cardamom, so I talk about it second. Although “first” would be
>   the obvious choice thanks to whole number of benefits one can reap
>   from cinnamon spiked coffee. Cinnamon is truly an amazing spice.
>   Adding it to coffee will help decrease the negative acidic effects
>   coffee has on your body. Cinnamon cleans your blood, promotes better
>   blood flow, warms you up inside and decreases inflammation. It is an
>   amazing natural home-made help during cold and flu season. Yes, treat
>   your cold with cinnamon coffee! Or at least try one time. You’ll see
>   the difference. Ethnoscience (or maybe better – Folk Medicine) states
>   and insists, that cinnamon coffee can better your mood, positively
>   stimulate nervous system, improve clarity of your vision. And on top
>   of all, the aroma coming from cinnamon coffee mug is simply
>   indescribably good. You gotta try it! Just one little pinch of organic
>   cinnamon powder and you’ll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it necessarily brings out any flavors in the coffee, but I think it complements some of the notes in coffee. I've heard cinnamon described as "sweet" tasting so maybe that's why it was perceived as being better tasting?

Making it is pretty simple, just put a few dashes in your grinds before brewing (I'd experiment with the amount to see what you like best but recommend starting with a small amount - it can be a pretty potent spice) and you'll get all of the cinnamon flavor but none of the grittiness of the cinnamon. I've also made French press coffee throwing a half a cinnamon stick in and that comes out pretty good too.